# What does -webkit-transform: matrix3d() do?

Tags: javascript, css, graphics, 3d

I need to apply 3D transformations(non affine/perspective) on images inside the html canvas. I have used matrix3d() on a div to do this but since Matrix3d() can only be used on DOM elements, I am unable to figure out a way to do these transformations on objects inside html canvas. In order to to this, I need to write a script which can do the same operations as matrix3d() transform does. 
More specifically, I need to know the meaning of 16 values passed as arguments in matrix3d() function and what mathematical operations they undergo.

Comment: do a similar transform, how, and to what, exactly?

Comment: I need to create a javascript function which does the same thing as matrix3d() transform does. But to create such a function, I first need to understand what operations are taking place in matrix3d() function.

Comment: That's still very unclear.  `matrix3d` from CSS3 is used to apply 3D transformations to an element on the page.  CSS3 is the _only_ way of doing this, so if you want to apply the same transformation via JS code you have to just dynamically apply such a CSS3 style to your page (or element).

Comment: Yes you are correct that CSS3D is used to apply transformations to an element on the page. I need to apply 3D transformations on images inside the html canvas. I have used matrix3d() on a div to do this: http://128.199.208.55/ Now I am unable to figure out a way to do these transformations on objects inside html canvas, hence I need to write a script which can do these transformations and then I plan to apply the script on the canvas objects. Hope I have made myself clear?

Comment: That's much clearer, but unfortunately extremely hard to implement.  A canvas is a 2D pixel array and "rasterizing" drawing operations from 3D space into 2D is difficult.  You may have better luck using SVG (on supported browsers) or even WebGL.

Comment: I know. None the less, I need to do it using javascript for it to be compatible with cell phone browsers. If you are aware of a source which offers explanation on matrix3d() then kindly post here. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer explaining the transformation matrix, but that's as far as I can go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 16 numbers represent the values contained in a 4x4 homogenous transformation matrix ([see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)).  The *general* form is that for an input coordinate `A` the components of the output coordinate `B` and given a CSS style of:

```
matrix3d(a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2, a3, b3, c3, d3, a4, b4, c4, d4)
```

are:

```
B_x = A_x * a1 + A_y * a2 + A_z * a_3 + a4;
B_y = A_x * b1 + A_y * b2 + A_z * b_3 + b4;
B_Z = A_x * c1 + A_y * c2 + A_z * c_3 + c4;
```

[this assumes the typical values of `d1 = d2 = d3 = 0`, and `d4 = 1`]

Thus the vector `[a4, b4, c4]` corresponds to a translation, and the remaining 9 values represent scaling and rotation transforms.

Comment: Can you tell what are the positions(index numbers) of the variables you have used above in the matrix3d() function?

Comment: @AnishShah OK, I've added those, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function